# How to enable screen rotation Sony Vaio Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-registry, display-rotation

I've got a sony vaio SA laptop. Since reformatting it to the Sony OEM windows 7 I couldn't change the screen orientation. 
I thought maybe it's an option in the registry that needs changing but I can't find a reference to such a registry option. 
Can anyone help me?
For clarification, the orientation option is turned off completely for some reason. That means that I can't see it in the screen resolution window and can't change it in the ATI/Intel graphic options.
Thanks in advance!